# Erro no parametro nome do construtor ObjectParameter C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Quando passo uma variável string para o parâmetro do ObjetParameter da o seguinte erro.

```
   string nomeParameter = sql.Substring(startPosition, stopPosition - startPosition);

   ObjectParameter parameter = new ObjectParameter(nomeParameter, parameters[contador]);
```

> Additional information: The specified parameter name 'DESCRICAO ' is not valid. Parameter names must begin with a letter and can only contain letters, numbers, and underscores.

Se passar o parâmetro conforme abaixo, o erro não ocorre:

```
   ObjectParameter parameter = new ObjectParameter("DESCRICAO", parameters[contador]);
```

Será que teria algum problema com Culture? mas o construtor do objeto não proporcionar colocar a Culture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não faço ideia do que você está fazendo, mas é bem claro, pela descrição do erro, que o problema é causado pelo espaço no final da *string*.

Remova mais um carácter do final da *string* que vai funcionar.

```
string nomeParameter = sql.Substring(startPosition, stopPosition - startPosition + 1);
ObjectParameter parameter = new ObjectParameter(nomeParameter, parameters[contador]);
```

Comment: Realmente era isso amigo, coloquei o trim e deu certro, muito obrigado.

Comment: não me atentei a isso.. =(